# Cannot access /me/drive/root/children (nor any driveItem object)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph cannot access any driveItem object (i.e. GET /me/drive/root/children)

I am working on a Proof Of Concept web app which (among other things) accesses some Excel workbooks (on SharePoint or OneDrive) from the authenticated user.

It is based on Microsoft tutorial [Build Node.js Express apps with Microsoft Graph]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node for most of the Ms Graph aspects.
- Azure AD authentication of the end user (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)
- App registered in AAD portal (Implicit grant: `ID tokens`, API Permissions for Ms Graph include `Files.ReadWrite.All` and `Sites.ReadWrite.All`)

Using `Microsoft Graph Explorer` we validated API queries to the relevant driveItem resources with the following paths
- `/drives/<id>/items/<id>` and `/shares/<shareId>/driveItem` for SharePoint
- `/me/drive/items/<id>` for OneDrive

But all those API queries fails when run from the web app (while other graph calls like `/me/`, `/me/drive/` and `/me/drive/root/` work fine)

GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<id>/items/<id>`

```
{
  statusCode: 404,
  code: 'itemNotFound',
  message: 'The resource could not be found.',
  requestId: 'cd35bf5b-1577-420e-980d-c1c2811a6fff',
  date: 2019-09-18T08:42:05.000Z,
  body:
   '{"code":"itemNotFound","message":"The resource could not be found.","innerError":{"request-id":"cd35bf5b-1577-420e-980d-c1c2811a6fff","date":"2019-09-18T10:42:05"}}' }
```

GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/<shareId>/driveItem`

```
{
  statusCode: 403,
  code: 'accessDenied',
  message: 'The caller does not have permission to perform the action.',
  requestId: '1d3bba03-6c15-41f0-9de5-979ce42127b5',
  date: 2019-09-18T08:46:37.000Z,
  body:
   '{"code":"accessDenied","message":"The caller does not have permission to perform the action.","innerError":{"request-id":"1d3bba03-6c15-41f0-9de5-979ce42127b5","date":"2019-09-18T10:46:37"}}' }
```

I very likely overlooked something like how the token is handled, but I couldn't find what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

Granting permissions within the Azur AD portal is useless if during authentication the app does not also specify those permissions in its scope.

In my case, adding `files.readwrite.all` solved the problem.

in `.env`

```
OAUTH_SCOPES='profile files.readwrite.all mail.send user.read'
```

Which is used for Passport AAD:

```
import { IOIDCStrategyOptionWithoutRequest } from 'passport-azure-ad';

const oidcOptions: IOIDCStrategyOptionWithoutRequest = {
  allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
  clientID: oauthOptions.client.id,
  clientSecret: oauthOptions.client.secret,
  identityMetadata: `${oauthOptions.auth.tokenHost}${process.env.OAUTH_ID_METADATA}`,
  loggingLevel: 'info',
  passReqToCallback: false,
  redirectUrl: process.env.OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI!,
  responseMode: 'form_post',
  responseType: 'code id_token',
  scope: process.env.OAUTH_SCOPES!.split(' '),
  validateIssuer: false,
};
```

Comment: Hello, how do I obtain {drive-id} in below two queries? I am trying to read data using Graph. GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}
GET /drives/{drive-id}/root:/{item-path}