# 401 Unauthorized Error When Accessing '/me/drive/root/children' in React App with Microsoft Graph API / Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, msal-react

I am creating a React app and using the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve files from One Drive.

When I call "/me", I am able to successfully get information about the account:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": [NAME],
    "givenName": null,
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": [EMAIL],
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": null,
    "userPrincipalName": [USER_PRINCIPAL_NAME]
    "id": [ID]
}
```

However, when I call "/me/drive/root/children", I get a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
HTTPMessageHandler.ts:29 
        
        
       GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children 401 (Unauthorized)
(anonymous) @ HTTPMessageHandler.ts:29
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
execute @ HTTPMessageHandler.ts:28
(anonymous) @ TelemetryHandler.ts:91
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
execute @ TelemetryHandler.ts:66
(anonymous) @ RetryHandler.ts:173
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
executeWithRetry @ RetryHandler.ts:172
(anonymous) @ RetryHandler.ts:196
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
execute @ RetryHandler.ts:192
(anonymous) @ AuthenticationHandler.ts:88
fulfilled @ tslib.es6.mjs:118
Promise.then (async)
step @ tslib.es6.mjs:120
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
execute @ AuthenticationHandler.ts:63
(anonymous) @ HTTPClient.ts:88
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
sendRequest @ HTTPClient.ts:81
(anonymous) @ GraphRequest.ts:372
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
send @ GraphRequest.ts:366
(anonymous) @ GraphRequest.ts:635
(anonymous) @ tslib.es6.mjs:121
__awaiter @ tslib.es6.mjs:117
get @ GraphRequest.ts:630
getData @ initializeAuthProcess.js:26
initializeAuthProcess @ initializeAuthProcess.js:12
await in initializeAuthProcess (async)
(anonymous) @ App.js:31
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
initializeAuthProcess.js:29 getData error Error: There has been an error authenticating the request.
    at GraphErrorHandler.constructErrorFromResponse (GraphErrorHandler.ts:77:1)
    at GraphErrorHandler.<anonymous> (GraphErrorHandler.ts:104:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at tslib.es6.mjs:121:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.mjs:117:1)
    at GraphErrorHandler.getError (GraphErrorHandler.ts:101:1)
    at GraphRequest.<anonymous> (GraphRequest.ts:391:1)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (tslib.es6.mjs:119:1)
```

I did see [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57991060/cannot-access-me-drive-root-children-nor-any-driveitem-object) where a user similarly could not access the /me/drive/root/children API call.

Their problem was that they did not specify the Files.ReadWrite.All permission in the scope. I made sure to include that permissions. Please see my initializeAuthProcess function:

```
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';

export const initializeAuthProcess = async (instance) => {
    try {
      await instance.initialize();
      const authResponse = await instance.loginPopup({
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
        scopes: ["User.Read", "User.Read.All", "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.ReadWrite", "User.ReadWrite.All", "Files.Read", "Files.Read.All", "Files.Read.Selected", "Files.ReadWrite", "Files.ReadWrite.All", "Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder", "Files.ReadWrite.Selected"],
        prompt: "select_account"
      });
      const accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;
      getData(accessToken)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("initializeAuthProcess error", e);
    }
};

async function getData(accessToken) {
    const client = Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) => {
        done(null, accessToken);
      },
    });
  
    try {
      const data = await client.api('/me/drive/root/children').get();
      console.log("data", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("getData error", error);
    }
}
```

And this is my App.js:

```
import {
  PublicClientApplication
} from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { MsalProvider, useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { initializeAuthProcess } from "./functions/initializeAuthProcess";

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: [clientId],
    authority: [authority],
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
};

const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

function App() {
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={pca}>
      <OneDriveFiles />
    </MsalProvider>
  );
}

function OneDriveFiles() {
  const { accounts, instance } = useMsal();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(instance){
      initializeAuthProcess(instance);
    }

  }, [accounts, instance]);

  return null;
}

export default App;
```

I also made sure that all these permissions were granted for the project in the Azure Active Directory:

[image]

I have also tried with two different Microsoft accounts, both with an active One Drive.

**Do you know why I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error with the "/me/drive/root/children" API call?**

Comment: Could you try decoding your access token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check values of `aud` & `scp` claims?

Comment: @Sridevi when I decode the access token, I get 

"scp": "Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.Read.Selected Files.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder Files.ReadWrite.Selected openid profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All email"

"aud": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: Are you getting the results when you run the same query `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children` in [Graph Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children/) like [this](https://i.imgur.com/BktyCVD.png)?

Comment: @Sridevi

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('vaibhavverma9%40gmail.com')/drive/root/children",
    "@odata.count": 4,
    "@microsoft.graph.tips": "Use $select to choose only the properties your app needs, as this can lead to performance improvements. For example: GET me/drive/root/children?$select=audio,bundle",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": [],
....

Comment: Could you include the account type of your registered application? You can find it in `Authentication` tab like [this](https://i.imgur.com/D1Scmcc.png)

Comment: Hi @Sridevi! These are my supported account types for my registered application:

Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)
All users with a work or school, or personal Microsoft account can use your application or API. This includes Office 365 subscribers.

Comment: Try changing **scopes** value to `https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All` and check what response you are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256357/discussion-between-sridevi-and-vaibhav-verma).